# what are the pros and cons of using Hibernate validator vs Apache bean validation?

Tags: bean-validation, hibernate-validator

what are the pros and cons of using Hibernate validator vs  Apache bean validation(Apache bVal)?

using them for validation for mongodb data which one should i prefer ?

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate Validator is the reference implementation of Bean Validation and so far the only certified implementation of Bean Validation 1.1. See also - http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/certified/.

To my knowledge the latest release of BVal just complies to the Bean Validation 1.0 spec. Also the latest release of BVal is according to the download site (http://bval.apache.org/downloads.html) from 2012, whereas Hibernate Validator is actively maintained with a release just a couple of weeks old.